# chemformula: reaction arrows not displayed

Tags: arrows, mhchem, chemmacros, chemformula

lately I've been having trouble with chemical equations in the reaction-environment. To be specific, neither reaction arrows nor hyphens are displayed after compiling the pdf. Instead, a blank space is inserted where the arrow/hyphen should be. Molecular formulas are depicted correctly, though. I'm using TeX Live with the TeXstudio editor, the installed version of my chemmacros-package is 5.8b. Note that upon changing `\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}` to `\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}` in the following MWE the reaction arrow as well as the hyphen between Ph and CHO get depicted correctly, so I figure there must be something wrong regarding the chemformula-package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}

    \begin{reaction*}
        2 H2 + O2 -> 2 H2O
    \end{reaction*}

    \begin{reaction*}
        Ph-CHO
    \end{reaction*}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Kind regards,
shulgin

Answer (score 4):

While I can't give you the details of what happens, I can tell you that this works fine if you remove the `dvips` option for `graphics`, or if you actually use `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf` to generate the PDF. I assume you have been using `pdflatex` (?), so you've specified in the code one particular compilation sequence (involving `dvips`), but using a different one. This can cause various problems.

In general you shouldn't be specifying the driver (`dvips` in this case) for packages like `graphics` and `hyperref`, they figure out the correct one on their own. And you would probably want to load `graphicx` (with an `x`), most recent documentation use the syntax specified by that, and not the older `graphics`.

[image: code output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}

    \begin{reaction*}
        2 H2 + O2 -> 2 H2O
    \end{reaction*}

    \begin{reaction*}
        Ph-CHO
    \end{reaction*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick, thank you! I know there must have been a reason for me to specify [dvips] as the driver for the graphics package, although I haven't noticed anything unusual in my document after using graphicx without further options. Anyways, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to realize, also, your reaction with arrows displayed using `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}`. In fact you have with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\[\ce{2 H2 + O2 -> 2 H2O}\]
\[\ce{Ph-CHO}\]

\end{document}
```

this output:

[image]