# Chemformula doesnt display arrows (not using dvips)

Tags: chemmacros, chemformula

I've been trying a simple reaction with `chemformula` but it doesnt display the arrows. There is a similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389959/chemformula-reaction-arrows-not-displayed) but the solution doesn't work  for me (I'm not using dvips).

Here is a **MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}


\begin{document}

\ch{glucosa_{(s)} <=> glucosa_{(aq)}}


\end{document}
```

The reported error is:

```
*************************************************
* chemmacros warning: "no-greek"
* 
* You haven't loaded any package for upright Greek letters or no unique choice
* was possible. Either load one of packages specified in the manual or select
* a chemgreek mapping manually.
*************************************************

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elements/elements_names_spanish.d
ef)

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! chemformula error: "unknown-arrow"
! 
! The arrow type <=> doesn't exist on line 26.
! 
! See the chemformula documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................  

l.26 \ch{glucosa_{(s)} <=> glucosa_{(aq)}}
```

Comment: spanish babel makes `>` and `<` characters active. you could try passing `es-noquoting` when loading babel.

Comment: Feel free to accept @TeXnician’s answer, he goes into more detail than I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove `babel`'s modifications (making `>` and `<` active).

[image: chemformula]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\let\chold\ch
\renewcommand\ch[1]{%
    \catcode`<=12
    \catcode`>=12
    \chold{#1}%
    \catcode`<=\active
    \catcode`>=\active
}

\begin{document}
<<Test>>

\ch{glucosa_{(s)} <=> glucosa_{(aq)}}

<<Test>>
\end{document}
```

---

Alternative (mentioned by Troy in the comments):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}
<<Test>>

\ch{glucosa_{(s)} <=> glucosa_{(aq)}}

<<Test>>
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the solution work, but what is the issue? I couldn't understand it...< and > are active  in Spanish language? I can't guess why...

Comment: @santimirandarp Do you see the quotes in the screenshot? That's not simply `<<`, but a quote glyph. Therefore, it has to be active. Babel activates many characters in many different languages, so it's always wise to read the documentation.