# Czech babel and chemmacros clash - reaction arrow not displayed

Tags: babel, incompatibility, chemistry, chemmacros

Clash between czech babel and chemacros in displaying reaction arrows, resulting in

```
chemformula error: "unknown-arrow"
The arrow type <-> doesn't exist on line 19.
```

If czech babel is switched of or spanish is used, it works.

How to make it work together? Repair it in similar way as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451387/chemformula-doesnt-display-arrows-not-using-dvips)?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
% \usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel} %all working with spanish babel
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document} <<Test>>

\ch{1 glucosa_{(s)} <=>> glucosa_{(aq)}} %working

\ch{2 glucosa_{(s)} <-> glucosa_{(aq)}} %not working

\ch{3 glucosa_{(s)} -> glucosa_{(aq)}} %not working

\begin{reaction} 4 glucosa_{(s)} <=> glucosa_{(aq)} %working \end{reaction}

\begin{reaction} 5 glucosa_{(s)} <-> glucosa_{(aq)} %not working
\end{reaction}

<<Test>> 
\end{document}
```

Similar issues:

[Spanish babel and chemformula package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157095/spanish-babel-and-chemformula-package)

[Chemformula doesnt display arrows (not using dvips)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451387/chemformula-doesnt-display-arrows-not-using-dvips)

Comment: it's a similar problem: the character `-` is made active by `czech` babel, which you have to deactivate it when using these chemmacros commands. A catch-all solution is just to use `\shorthandoff{-}` before you use these `\ch` etc., and you can reactivate the shorthand with `\shorthandon{-}` after you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off `shorthands`:

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,czech]{babel}
```